# Rails 4 Koala: Webhook when publish in Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, twitter, koala-gem

Im building a Social network, users can connect their accounts with Facebook and Tweeter, they should be able to select an option: "synchronize publications"

if they select that option I need to synchronize publications with Facebook, so when they publish in Facebook that should be also published in my app. I think this can be achieved through a web hook, but I can't find anything useful in the web...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a entire section dedicated to webhooks:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

adding subscriptions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/app/subscriptions

and viewing subscribed apps:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps